# Get column value from another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables:

User and Order

A Order belongs to a User, in a way that the Order table has a column called user_id. So, for example, a row in Order table would look like:

```
id: 4
description: "pair of shoes"
price: 18.40
user_id: 1
```

And a User row would look like:

```
id: 1
email: "myemail@gmail.com"
name: "John"
```

How would I go if I want to get all the Orders, but instead of getting the user id, get the email?

Comment: The correct answer to your question is to use JOIN, but you already marked in your question you want to use that. What have you tried? Is there something you ommited?

Answer (score 5):

A simple `JOIN` will do the trick

```
SELECT o.id, 
       o.description, 
       o.price,
       u.email
  FROM "order" o JOIN "user" u
    ON o.user_id = u.id
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |   DESCRIPTION | PRICE |             EMAIL |
--------------------------------------------------
|  4 | pair of shoes |  18.4 | myemail@gmail.com |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5dfc8/2)** demo

Further reading [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)